# Apache Curator creatingParentsIfNeeded inTransaction

Tags: apache, apache-curator

TransactionCreateBuilder does not seem to support "creatingParentsIfNeeded". This is an operation supported by the typical CreateBuilder. I would ideally want to do:

curatorTransaction.create().creatingParentsIfNeeded().forPath(key, value).and()..

Is this possible at all? or is it a restriction on Zookeeper (not supporting atomic subpath manipulations)

Thanks!

Comment: It might be possible. I suggest opening an issue in Curator's Jira

Comment: Also, what's the need here? There's no particular benefit for this being transactional.

Comment: I suppose I can manually write the parent path myself if it does not exist, and you are right this doesn't have to be transactional, just makes for cleaner code.